# Flask tutorial: AttributeError teardown_appcontext

Tags: python, flask

I'm a beginner of Python and Flask.
I was going through Flask tutorial up to "[Define and Access the Database](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/database/)" section.

Wrote up all codes, saved, and did below on Windows command prompt.

```
flask init-db
```

However, got received the error on the command prompt as follows.

```
AttributeError: 'ellipsis' object has no attribute 'teardown_appcontext'
```

I doublechecked the codes to confirm it's written exactly in a way that tutorial specifies and it actually worked fine until [the previous section](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/factory/).
Searched through Stackoverflows if there is any similar questions, but ended up not finding out a clear cause.

Any advises? Thank you very much for your support.

**--Additions--**

Thanks Joost. Here is what I did.

**[Files layout image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDp54.jpg)**

**__init__.py**

```
import os

from flask import Flask

def create_app(test_config=None):
    # create and configure the app
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY='dev',
        DATABASE=os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'flaskr.sqlite'),
    )

    if test_config is None:
        # Load the instance config, if it exists, when not testing
        app.config.from_pyfile('config.py', silent=True)
    else:
        # Load the test config if passed in
        app.config.from_mapping(test_config)

    # ensure the instance floder exists
    try:
        os.makedirs(app.instance_path)
    except OSError:
        pass

    # a simple page that says hello
    @app.route('/hello')
    def hello():
        return 'Hello, World!'

def create_app():
    app = ...
    # existing code omitted

    from . import db
    db.init_app(app)

    return app
```

**db.py**

```
import sqlite3

import click
from flask import current_app, g
from flask.cli import with_appcontext

def get_db():
    if 'db' not in g:
        g.db = sqlite3.connect(
            current_app.config['DATABASE'],
            detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES
        )
        g.db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row

    return g.db

def close_db(e=None):
    db = g.pop('db', None)

    if db is not None:
        db.close()

def init_db():
    db = get_db()

    with current_app.open_resource('schema.sql') as f:
        db.executescript(f.read().decode('utf8'))

@click.command('init-db')
@with_appcontext
def init_db_command():
    """Clear the exisitng data and create new tables."""
    init_db()
    click.echo('Initialized the database.')

def init_app(app):
    app.teardown_appcontext(close_db)
    app.cli.add_command(init_db_command)
```

**schema.sql**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS post;

CREATE TABLE user (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  username TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  password TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE post (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  author_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  title TEXT NOT NULL,
  body TEXT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES user (id)
);
```

And finally I did on the command prompt:

```
set FLASK_APP=flaskr
set FLASK_ENV=development
flask init-db
```

However it returned [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Q5aV.jpg).

Any advises?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you show how what code you copied in which files? Or, just show the files and their content

Comment: @Joost  Thanks for your reply. I added some more details what I did. Appreciate your help. thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You defined `create_app()` twice. To solve your problem, make the following change in your `__init__.py` files:

```
import os

from flask import Flask


def create_app(test_config=None):
    """ Application factory function """
    # create and configure the app
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY='dev',
        DATABASE=os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'flaskr.sqlite'),
    )

    if test_config is None:
        # load the instance config, if it exists, when not testing
        app.config.from_pyfile('config.py', silent=True)
    else:
        # load the test config if passed in
        app.config.from_mapping(test_config)

    # ensure the instance folder exists
    try:
        os.makedirs(app.instance_path)
    except OSError:
        pass

    # a simple page that says hello
    @app.route('/hello')
    def hello():
        return 'Hello, World! Now We are Introducing Mr. Narendra Singh Parihar.THE BOSS !!'

    from . import db
    db.init_app(app)

    return app
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is in your **init**.py
I removed the second create_app() from your **init** file and edited it like below remember the app factory need to know where your db.py is while creating the app

```
 import os

    from flask import Flask

    def create_app(test_config=None):
        # create and configure the app
        app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
        app.config.from_mapping(
            SECRET_KEY='dev',
            DATABASE=os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'flaskr.sqlite'),
        )

        if test_config is None:
            # Load the instance config, if it exists, when not testing
            app.config.from_pyfile('config.py', silent=True)
        else:
            # Load the test config if passed in
            app.config.from_mapping(test_config)

        # ensure the instance floder exists
        try:
            os.makedirs(app.instance_path)
        except OSError:
            pass

        # a simple page that says hello
        @app.route('/hello')
        def hello():
            return 'Hello, World!'

        from . import db
        db.init_app(app)

        return app
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't replace the existing code with the new proposed one,
but you add to it,

so for example :

```
def create_app():
app = ...
# existing code omitted

from . import db
db.init_app(app)

return app
```

should be translated in your code by adding the two new lines :

```
from . import db
db.init_app(app)
```

to what's already there so far in the function, just before the last line.

```
return app
```

which should translate as other answers mentioned :

```
 def create_app(test_config=None):
        # create and configure the app
        app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
        app.config.from_mapping(
            SECRET_KEY='dev',
            DATABASE=os.path.join(app.instance_path, 'flaskr.sqlite'),
        )

        if test_config is None:
            # Load the instance config, if it exists, when not testing
            app.config.from_pyfile('config.py', silent=True)
        else:
            # Load the test config if passed in
            app.config.from_mapping(test_config)

        # ensure the instance floder exists
        try:
            os.makedirs(app.instance_path)
        except OSError:
            pass

        # a simple page that says hello
        @app.route('/hello')
        def hello():
            return 'Hello, World!'

        from . import db
        db.init_app(app)

        return app
```